# How to find the distance from a point to an edge on MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am tasked with creating a MATLAB script to determine the distance from the center (represented by the black dot) to the data points (represented as the blue dots). After determining that distance, I have to determine the difference between the blue dots and the black line. It is important that when determining the difference between the blue dots and the black line that the vector from the center have the same direction.

I am currently stuck on this part and am asking for any suggestions to help me get started.

Any help is truly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the MATLAB code you have used to generate the two graphs, or at least describe the equations that were used.

Comment: Your question is unclear: do you want the shortest distance or the distances to all the points? What do you call the "difference" between the lines?

Comment: What I understand is: Suppose there is **an infinite ray starting at the center point, it would intercept the two curves at two points**. The task is to find *that* distance, between those two points, and is to be found for all possible such pair of points.

Comment: An equation of the curve, or its form: Is it only a list of coordinates, or an actual function, would help solve us your problem.

Comment: @crazyGamer Like you said, I have to create and infinite ray starting at the center point that would intercept the two curves at two points. However, it has to do this for all points on the plot. These plots were based off a data set (list of coordinates), not an actual function.

Comment: Then, is it guaranteed that there are always two points that fall on some infinite ray? (As they are not an actual "curves", in the sense you can't determine all continuous values, and only have a set of coordinates.)

Comment: I've posted an answer assuming it is not guaranteed, however, the code should work for both cases. Due to the minimum information provided, I've assumed my own variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to provide a solution, assuming that you cannot guarantee that each coordinate in one curve has a counterpart in the other curve that falls on the same ray from the center.

#### Let:

```
origin % Center coordinate
c1 % N x 2 matrix where each row in a coordinate for curve 1
c2 % N x 2 matrix where each row in a coordinate for curve 2
```

#### Approach:

```
% Vectors from center point to each point on both curves
v1 = c1 - repmat(origin, size(c1, 1), 1)
v2 = c2 - repmat(origin, size(c2, 1), 1)

% Angles made by each coordinate with respect to center point
a1 = atan2(v1(:, 2), v1(:, 1))
a2 = atan2(v2(:, 2), v2(:, 1))

% Understand that, two points that pass through the same infinite ray 
% from the origin would have the same angle. Hence, we need to find all
% pairs of coordinates based on where `a1` and `a2` have the same value.

dists = zeros(size(c1, 1), 1)
matchingPoints = zeros(size(c1, 1), 2); % Just for extra information.

for i = 1:len(c1)
    matchInd = find(a2 == a1(i))
    % Can also use some error margin to overcome floating-point rounding-off errors.
    % Example: matchInd = find(abs(a2 - a1(i)) <= 1e-6)

    if isempty(matchInd)
        % Basically there was no point along that ray in second curve
        dists(i) = NaN;
        matchingPoints(i, :) = [NaN, NaN];
    else
        dists(i) = norm(c1(i) - c2(matchInd))
        matchingPoints(i, :) = c2(matchInd, :);
    end
end
```

Finally, the pair of points on the two curves that lie on same ray from origin is in `c1` and `matchingPoints` respectively, and the corresponding distances are in `dists`.

Comment: @MarkS You're welcome, I would appreciate if in that case you could mark the solution as accepted :)